# sqlite3 хочу сделать проверку , нет ли там учасника повторно

Tags: python, requests, sqlite3

```
db = sqlite3.connect('db_course24.db', check_same_thread=False)
    cursor = db.cursor()
    
    
    def db_table_val(user_id: int, user_name: str, user_surname: str, username: str):
        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO users (user_id, user_name, user_surname, username) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)',
                       (user_id, user_name, user_surname, username))
        db.commit()
    
    
    @bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
    def handle_start(message):
        user_markup = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True)
        user_markup.row('Почати')
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Доброго дня, ' + message.from_user.first_name +
                         '!\nЦе Курс Валют на сьогодні!',
                         reply_markup=user_markup)
        us_id = message.from_user.id
        us_name = message.from_user.first_name
        us_sname = message.from_user.last_name
        username = message.from_user.username
        result = cursor.execute('SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_id="us_id"').fetchall()
        if result is None:
            db_table_val(user_id=us_id, user_name=us_name, user_surname=us_sname, username=username)
            cursor.close()
        else:
            print('Have been.', message.from_user.username)
```

хелп..

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вопрос. Где именно ошибка в коде? Какие данные идут на вход? Какой результат должен быть?

Comment: когда пользователь делает /start , он не попадает в базу, а только срабативает else типо он есть

Comment: Надо так писать хотя бы: cursor.execute( f'SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_id="{us_id}"')

Comment: пробивал, ниже отвеча..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Еслии us_id в данном случае - это переменная для выборки, то её нужно объявить, как переменную, а в данном случае, она просто строка

```
result = cursor.execute(f'SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_id="{us_id}"').fetchall()
```

Здесь мы добавили форматирование строки (f'') и заключили us_id в фигурные скобки, объявив как переменную.

Не уверен, только в этом ли проблема здесь.

Если вы проверите выборку несуществующего значения, вам будет приходить не None, а пустой список []

Попробуйте сделать `if result == []:`

Comment: if result == []: - дает такой сигмент теста Expression can be simplified 
ну и саму проблему не решило, код рабочий, но в базу не попадает
если забрать ряд 
result = cursor.execute(f'SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_id="{us_id}"').fetchall()
все работает, только делает дубли раз за разом

Comment: На зарубежном форуме прочёл, что решилось вместо == [] и is None применили if not result:

Comment: Насчёт дублей не совсем понял, но если не хотите повторений значений в таблице, то просто стоит добавить параметр UNIQUE при создании таблицы в том поле, которые должно иметь уникальное значение

Comment: я создавал таблицу через sqlite3 (библиотеку) и как поставить уникальное здесь ни знаю и повлияет ли оно когда я поминяю значения в програме sqlitestudio.... если знаете ответ подскажите или силку на документацию)

Comment: В sqlite studio можете просто открыть нужную таблицу, зайти в Структура и два раза нажать на нужный столбец, там будет галочка Уникальность. Ставите и готово

Comment: https://www.schoolsw3.com/sql/sql_unique.php - здесь об этом также есть информация

Comment: большое спасибо за подсказки!!! мне помог вариант с - "if not results".
завтра попитаюсь ищо с галочкой
спасиба ,  берегите себя!)